# Wp Nav Menu div containers

Tags: menus, navigation

Hi I'm wanting to create a custom navigation menu that will require creating  div containers to hold the SUB-MENU set. In other words I want to do this:

```
  <ul class="left_menu">
     <li class="menu_item droped">
        <a class="top_link" href="#">Kurumsal</a>

     <div class="dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Misyon Vizyon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Satın Alma</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kariye</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bayilik Başvurusu</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="menu_item droped">
        <a class="top_link" href="#/">Ürünlerimiz</a>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">İnce Taneli Kumlar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">İri Taneli Kumlar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yalıtım Malzemeleri</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Yapı Kimyasalları</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </li>
</ul>
```

How would I go about adding this into the wp_nav_menu function? Do I add a filter in functions.php, or do I create a separate PHP file to do this?

Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, it sounds like you might need to use a custom walker for the `wp_nav_menu` call. To create a custom walker that modifies the wrapper for dropdown lists, start with this class:

```
<?php

class wpse_112127_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<div class="dropdown"><ul>' . "\n";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul></div>\n";
    }
}
```

Then, use your walker in your `wp_nav_menu` call:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'walker' => new wpse_112127_walker ) );
```

This code should hopefully get you started on using a custom walker for your use case. Let me know if you have any difficulties/questions!

Comment: otherwise to add <a class="top_link" href="#"> i edited  nav-menu-template.php

  $atts['xfn']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
   $atts['class']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';